# Showing more than 9 pictures with subplot and MNIST

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, mnist

First of all - sorry if this exact question does exist somewhere, but I just couldn't find it.
In a nutshell I'm working on the classic task to do a classifier to distinguish the numbers 9-10 from the MNIST dataset.

It's easy to find the code to show the first 9 numbers - it's

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
for i in range(9):  
pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
pyplot.imshow(train_X[i], cmap=pyplot.get_cmap('gray'))
pyplot.show()
```

, but the line

```
pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
```

is just confusing to me.
I read up on subplots and I know what this line does - but I have no idea how to show more than 9 numbers, as everytime I try to write something like

```
for i in range(10):
```

I always get

```
ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 9, not 10
```

Is there any possibility to show more than 9 numbers?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The subplot index is being specified but not the shape; for example, a 330-by-1 figure subplot (i.e. 330 rows, 1 column) would be: pyplot.subplot(330, 1, i + 1); but given that the loop ranges from 0 to 10 it seems you want a 10-by-1 or similarly: pyplot.subplot(10, 1, i + 1).

Comment: Unrelated, I found the `plt.subplot` with a 3-digit integer argument really annoying. I'd just use the three-argument call, e.g. `plt.subplot(5, 2, 1+i)`.